# Result of bit manipulation not as expected in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, bit-manipulation

I am building a websocket server implementation in Node.js (I know Socket.IO is a thing, but I like to work on lower level protocol implementations so I can better understand how they work). I've managed to get past the handshake stage, and I'm working on a frame object that will decode the composition of the bits in the frame into a higher level abstraction of what kind of frame it is.

When you decode the payload of the frame, you need to use a masking sequence that is provided in the frame's header, and perform a bitwise XOR like this:

```
this.DECODED = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.PAYLOAD_DATA.length; i++) {
    this.DECODED.push(this.PAYLOAD_DATA[i] ^ this.MASKING_KEY[i % 4]);
}
```

Hypothetically, I should then be able to parse these values to integers, and then get their characters using `String.fromCharCode()` to compose the sent message, however I am just getting gibberish instead of the expected message ("Hello, server!"), though the message is of the expected length.

```
class SocketFrame{
constructor(buffer){
    console.log(buffer.length);
    let bitBytes = buffer.toString('hex').match(/.{1,2}/g).map(hexToBin);
    this.FIN = (bitBytes[0][0]);
    this.RSV1 = (bitBytes[0][1]);
    this.RSV2 = (bitBytes[0][2]);
    this.RSV3 = (bitBytes[0][3]);
    this.OP_CODE = OPCODE_DICTIONARY[bitBytes[0].slice(4)]
    this.MASK = bitBytes[1][0];
    this.MASK_OFFSET = 0;
    this.PAYLOAD_LENGTH = parseInt(bitBytes[1].slice(1), 2);
    if(this.PAYLOAD_LENGTH === 126){
        this.PAYLOAD_LENGTH = parseInt(bitBytes[2] + bitBytes[3], 2);
        this.MASK_OFFSET = 2;
    }
    if(this.PAYLOAD_LENGTH === 127){
        this.PAYLOAD_LENGTH = parseInt(bitBytes[4] + bitBytes[6] + bitBytes[7] + bitBytes[8], 2);
        this.MASK_OFFSET = 6;
    }
    //this.MASKING_KEY = [bitBytes[2 + this.MASK_OFFSET], bitBytes[4 + this.MASK_OFFSET], bitBytes[4 + this.MASK_OFFSET], bitBytes[5 + this.MASK_OFFSET]];
    this.MASKING_KEY = [buffer[2 + this.MASK_OFFSET], buffer[4 + this.MASK_OFFSET], buffer[4 + this.MASK_OFFSET], buffer[5 + this.MASK_OFFSET]];
    // this.MASKING_KEY = this.MASKING_KEY.map((val)=>{return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val))});
    // this.PAYLOAD_DATA = bitBytes.slice(6 + this.MASK_OFFSET);
    this.PAYLOAD_DATA = buffer.slice(6 + this.MASK_OFFSET);
    this.DECODED = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.PAYLOAD_DATA.length; i++) {
        this.DECODED.push(this.PAYLOAD_DATA[i] ^ this.MASKING_KEY[i % 4]);
    }
    this.DECODED_STRING = this.DECODED.map((val)=>{
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val, 2))
    }).join("");
    console.log(this);
}
}
```

The constructor is passed a buffer, which is the frame, then converts this to an array of string representations of the bits in each byte, and then the other properties are set according to the specification of the websockets RFC. I believe that the issue is most likely with XORing string representations of the bits, rather than byte/hex values, although I tried converting the bit strings to integers (parseInt with a binary radix), but the XOR still produced gibberish. (To be fair, it is gibberish that matches the textual pattern of the intended string, just with shifted character values, so instead of two consecutive "L"s you'll get two consecutive random utf-8 characters). Is there a way to convert a string of 1s and 0s back into a byte object? I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Is something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/6xay90rL/) working for you? It converts a string with binary 1/0 into a byte.

Comment: You only have to mask if `this.MASK` is set. Did you check it?

Comment: I believe current WebSocket spec is to reject if MASK is not set (at least if originating from client)?

"   In the WebSocket Protocol, data is transmitted using a sequence of
   frames.  To avoid confusing network intermediaries (such as
   intercepting proxies) and for security reasons that are further
   discussed in Section 10.3, a client MUST mask all frames that it
   sends to the server (see Section 5.3 for further details)."

And yes, I checked.

Comment: @AWolf tried that, but still ending up with something like this:

`SocketFrame {
  FIN: '1',
  RSV1: '0',
  RSV2: '0',
  RSV3: '0',
  OP_CODE: 'TEXT',
  MASK: '1',
  MASK_OFFSET: 0,
  PAYLOAD_LENGTH: 13,
  MASKING_KEY: [ 231, 130, 163, 81 ],
  PAYLOAD_DATA: [ 175, 231, 207, 61, 136, 162, 240, 52, 149, 244, 198, 35, 198 ],
  DECODED: [ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 33 ],
  DECODED_STRING: 'rāĈĈđ2 āĔĘāĔ3' }`

(decoded should be "Hello Server!")

Comment: @AWolf actually, it did work. I just had to remove `parseInt` from this line `return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val, 2))`